# Matlab symbolic expression error

Tags: matlab

I created a symbolic expression and then tried to use `ezmesh` on it as seen in the code below:

```
>> z1 = sym('3*(1-x)^2*exp(-(x^2)-(y+1)^2)');
>> z2 = sym('-10*(x/5 - x^3 -Y^5)*exp(-x^2-y^2)');
>> z3 = sym(' - 1/3*exp(-(x+1)*2 - y^2)');
>> z = z1 + z2 + z3
z =
3*exp(- (y + 1)^2 - x^2)*(x - 1)^2 - exp(- y^2 - 2*x - 2)/3 + 10*exp(- x^2 - y^2)*(Y^5 + x^3 - x/5)
>> ezmesh(z)
```

I got the following error:

> ```
> Error using ezgraph3>ezfixfun (line 677)
> The expression exp(x.*-2.0-y.^2-2.0).*(-1.0./3.0)+exp(-(y+1.0).^2-x.^2).*(x-1.0).^2.*3.0+exp(-x.^2-y.^2).*(x.*(-1.0./5.0)+Y.^5+x.^3).*1.0e1 must only have 2 symbolic
> variables
> Error in ezgraph3>surfplot (line 535)
> [F,var] = ezfixfun(F,fargs,flabel);
> Error in ezgraph3 (line 48)
>    [dummy,h] = surfplot(f,domain,surfstyle,cax,Npts,fixdomain,flabel,fargs);
> Error in ezmesh (line 65)
>     h = ezgraph3('mesh',args{:});
> Error in sym/ezhelper (line 1074)
>             fcn(F,varargin{:});
> Error in sym/ezmesh (line 51)
> ezhelper(@ezmesh,f,varargin{:});
> ```

However, when I looked up the peaks function in the documentation, I found a very similar expression that worked with `ezmesh`. Can anyone explain the differences?

```
z =  3*(1-x).^2.*exp(-(x.^2) - (y+1).^2) ... 
     - 10*(x/5 - x.^3 - y.^5).*exp(-x.^2-y.^2) ... 
     - 1/3*exp(-(x+1).^2 - y.^2)
```

Comment: The capital `Y` versus `y`?

Comment: "must only have 2 symbolic variables" see how the error message told you exactly what the problem was? Always read Matlab error messages, they are (nearly always) very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Error "must only have 2 symbolic variables" means there's more than 2 variables.
You had an capital `Y` in one place instead of `y`, fixed:

```
z1 = sym('3*(1-x)^2*exp(-(x^2)-(y+1)^2)');
z2 = sym('-10*(x/5 - x^3 -y^5)*exp(-x^2-y^2)');
z3 = sym(' - 1/3*exp(-(x+1)*2 - y^2)');
z = z1 + z2 + z3;
ezmesh(z)
```